# rails - filter results based on applying a condition on join table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have `trips` and `transit_locations` im my rails app. What I am trying to do is filter the trips whose last two transit_locations `created_at` difference is `< 1 day`. And this is how I am querying currently

```
@trips = Trip.eager_load(:transit_locations => [:geoname])
.group("transit_locations.trip_id, trips.id")
.having("count(transit_locations.id) > 1")
.order("transit_locations.trip_id desc, trips.id desc")
```

I need to filter trips if their last two trasit_locations are created with in a day

Any kind of help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `where("DATE(created_at) = ?", Date.today)` does this help?

Comment: I need check created_at difference for last two transit locations is < 1 day

Comment: means you want to fetch data of yeasterday?

Comment: no. if add a transit locations at 11:00pm and another at 6:00am on the next day. both are created at 2 different days. but time difference is `< 24 hours`.

Comment: `where(created_at: 24.hours.ago..Time.now)`

Comment: But created_at is ambigiuos on both tables, if I use above code it just applys that condition on trips table not transit_locations @uzaif

Comment: When you say "difference is < 1 day," do you mean less than one day ago (from present) or do you mean less than one day apart (regardless of how long ago)?

Comment: less than one day apart regardless of how long ago.

Comment: That's a tough question. You will probably need to resort to raw SQL. Maybe better to restyle your question, try to get the answer in pure SQL, and then try to implement in Rails (using a raw SQL request if necessary).

Comment: thanks for the valuable suggession @moveson